# Having problems using cURL in EC2 AWS

Tags: ubuntu, curl, amazon-ec2

I just create an instance of EC2 with Ubuntu and I installed php 7.0 and I have installed curl with the version 7.47.

I have a project that works as expected in localhost. I uploaded to Github and I cloned it into my ubuntu server. When I try to access a php page where cURL is used, the page gets opened, but shows this message: `CURL not supported. (introduced in PHP 4.0.2)`.

As I'm new in this field, I don't know if I should show any config file or something. Just ask whatever you'd need. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody is in this case in the future, what happened to me is that I didn't have the composer installed. Here I leave a guide of how to install it properly.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-composer-on-ubuntu-14-04

Just after I did it everything started to work as expected.